# user defaults setting a flag based on value found in for loop not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to find if a rating named "CASE OF COUNT" is present
and setting a flag if it not present.Although **self.enterdByuser** is being correctly set but the hide always stays at **YES** I  don't know what i am doing wrong.I am setting the flag to user defaults to use it in latter time.Thanks

```
- (NSMutableArray *) removeCaseOfCount:(NSArray *) ratings {
        NSMutableArray *ratingsLocal = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        
        BOOL hide = NO;
        for (Rating *rating in ratings) {
            NSLog(@"rating names %@",rating.name);
            if ([[Audt sharedInspection] checkOD]) {
                if (![[rating.od uppercaseString] isEqualToString:ODCases]) {
                    [ratingsLocal addObject:rating];
                } else {
                    self.currentAudit.countOfCasesRatingPresent = YES;
                    int cCasesFromAnswer = [rating.ratingAnswerFromUI integerValue];
                    self.cCEnteredByTheUser = cCasesFromAnswer;
                    [ratingsLocal addObject:rating];
                }
            } else {
                if((!([rating.name compare:@"CASE OF COUNT" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame))) {
                    self.enterdByuser = 1;
                    hide = YES;
                    [ratingsLocal addObject:rating];
                } else {
                    hide = NO;
                    self.ca.Present = YES;
                    [ratingsLocal addObject:rating];
                }
            }
        }
        
        [userDefaults setBool:hide forKey:@"cCountIsEmpty"];
        return ratingsLocal;
    }
```

Comment: You are setting `hide` to NO in the `else`, so the final value of `hide` will depend on the last iteration of your loop that ends up executing that `if`. It isn't clear why you have multiple rating as an input but a single `hide` value; which rating do you want to hide?

Comment: So i want to hide  if the ratings array doesn't contain rating.name == "CASE OF COUNT" if thats the case i want to set hide = YES

Comment: @e.T55 - trying to understand your goal. You have multiple `Rating` objects... if **ANY** rating `.name` is "CASE OF COUNT" then `hide` should be `YES`? Or, if **ANY** rating `.name` is **NOT** "CASE OF COUNT" then `hide` should be `NO`?